# CSS Tables with links with strange color behavior

Tags: html, css

I've got a question. I'm trying to make a CSS table with alternating colored rows, like [this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/table-markup/#section_3). However, I want some of the content of the table to have links, and I'm finding that the background of the text of those cells is behaving oddly (namely, taking the background color of the wrong row for half of the rows). I'm quite new to CSS, so it's possible I'm making an obvious mistake. Screenshot:

[Funky link bg coloration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRUf3.png)

And MWE code:

```
<html>

  <style type="text/css">

  table.t2 {
  }
  .t2 th, .t2 td {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background: #fbd7b4;
  }

  .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) *:nth-child(even), .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(even) *:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f3eddd;
  } 
</style>

  <table class="t2" summary="blah">
    <caption>hey </caption>

    <thead>
<tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr><th colspan="4">double </th></tr>
</tfoot>-
<tbody>
<tr><th>A</th><td><a href="google.com">BBB Link</a> </td><td>CCCC</td><td> DDDDD</td></tr>
<tr><th>A</th><td><a href="google.com">BBB Link</a> </td><td>CCCC</td><td> DDDDD</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help fixing this would be much appreciated!

Comment: you have changed the bg colour of the TD but not the anchor `a` - you need to add another set of styles similar to this: `.t2 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) *:nth-child(even) a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want...

Just exclude the a element from coloring.

```html
<html>

  <style type="text/css">

  table.t2 {
  }
  .t2 th, .t2 td {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background: #fbd7b4;
  }

  .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) *:nth-child(even), .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(even) *:nth-child(odd):not(a) {
    background: #f3eddd;
  } 
</style>

  <table class="t2" summary="blah">
    <caption>hey </caption>

    <thead>
<tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr><th colspan="4">double </th></tr>
</tfoot>-
<tbody>
<tr><th>A</th><td><a href="google.com">BBB Link</a> </td><td>CCCC</td><td> DDDDD</td></tr>
<tr><th>A</th><td><a href="google.com">BBB Link</a> </td><td>CCCC</td><td> DDDDD</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants every other cell to alternate colours (like a chess pattern)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the background colour of the `<a>` element. Something like this:

```
  .t2 th, .t2 td, .t2 td a, .t2 td a {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background: #fbd7b4;
  }

  .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) *:nth-child(even), .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(even) *:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f3eddd;
  } 

  .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) *:nth-child(even) a, .t2 tbody tr:nth-child(even) *:nth-child(odd) a{
    background: #f3eddd;
  }
```